# How to control Spring-WS namespace single or double quote with XSLT

Tags: xslt, spring-ws, saxon, axiom, woodstox

**I want to change the double quotes to single quotes for a single namespace declaration in my document, while leaving all other namespace declarations as double quotes. How can I do this?**

Here's the response document from the server:

> `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><soapenv:Envelope
>   xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><InquiryResponse
>   xmlns="http://www.openuri.org/"><Header><HeaderAttr1>abcd</HeaderAttr1><HeaderAttr2>xxx</HeaderAttr2><HeaderAttr3>string</HeaderAttr3></Header><Body><InquiryResult><ResultItem1>theresulttext</ResultItem1><ResultItem2>abcd</ResultItem2><ResultItem3>0</ResultItem3></InquiryResult></Body></InquiryResponse></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>`

I need something like (note that open:InquiryResponse has ' not ").

> `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <SOAP-ENV:Envelope
>   xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
>   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
>   <open:InquiryResponse
>   xmlns:open='http://www.openuri.org/'><open:Header><open:HeaderAttr1>abcd</open:HeaderAttr1><open:HeaderAttr2>xxx</open:HeaderAttr2><open:HeaderAttr3>string</open:HeaderAttr3></open:Header><open:Body><open:InquiryResult><open:ResultItem1>theresulttext</open:ResultItem1><open:ResultItem2>abcd</open:ResultItem2><open:ResultItem3>0</open:ResultItem3></open:InquiryResult></open:Body></open:InquiryResponse>
>   </SOAP-ENV:Body> </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>`

I have been able to do namespace prefix change, additional namespace declarations, whitespace fixups, character set change, all I need now is to change those two bytes.

I'm using Spring WS + Woodstox + Axiom to build a simple inquiry web service. It's a replacement for an existing service and I would like to make it byte-for-byte identical ($$ reasons). I can get the XML to identical type, but we don't know at this point which consumers use a grep or regex to find the data.

I am trying to attack this problem so far using an XSLT and PayloadTransformingInterceptor. I would be interested in other options as well.

Comment: It is not clear what your actual question is. Is it simply: how to convert double quotes to single quotes in relation to XML attribute delimiters?

Comment: My first thought is, that if you believe you have a need to convert double quotes to single quotes, then you are doing it wrong. If you have any tools which require byte-for-byte indenticality of XML documents, then your tools are broken. I cannot imagine any problem where control of non-significant XML encoding data (like " over ') is a real issue. I suggest exploring the possibility that your tools are not broken and will work with double quotes.

Comment: Long question! First of all... oh I see Sean just said this. I'll restate it: existing apps that rely on a "byte for byte" formatting of XML are demanding something that is more than XML is designed to provide. That is the answer to "however I can't see why it needs to be quite so hard. An XSLT solution would be more elegant" -- because you're trying to use tools designed for transforming XML, to produce something that must be specified where XML is designed to be unspecified. Most likely you will need to use string-oriented tools, not just elegant XML tools, to produce this.

Comment: @SeanB.Durkin thanks for feedback; I've added the question at the top. Yes, you are right, I need to convert a *single* attribute delimiter from double to single quotes.

Comment: @SeanB.Durkin yourself and LarsH are both correct. This is a classic reality meets ideals thing in that for the sake of two bytes of XML we are going to cost ourselves a huge $$ amount to test across a number of systems not in our control. It is an extremely risk averse environment. I agree with your sentiments and I take it that "there is no XML solution, use a string-oriented solution".

Answer (score 1):

Comments are pretty much correct: there is no "clean" programmatic solution to configuring low-levels with such precision. And given fragility, you are best off using textual mangling; most likely regexps would work well enough if this is for testing or such.

Answer (score 0):

After re-reading your question and examples a few times I think I understand the problem :)

I think you should take a look at the [PayloadTransformingInterceptor](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/site/apidocs/org/springframework/ws/server/endpoint/interceptor/PayloadTransformingInterceptor.html). You can transform the incoming and outgoing messages in that interceptor. A typical usage of that interceptor is to support an older version of your wsdl by transforming it to the new version. This interceptor can work both ways - in your case only outgoing.

I'm not sure if this can be fixed by using XSLT. If not, you can create your own Interceptor to provide the specific string replacement functionality you need.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to drop Spring-WS, and instead move to CXF. CXF allows interceptors at any stage of processing, and hence full access to the bytes of the message stream. Ugly, but working. Build an interceptor to hook the OutputStream at PRE_STREAM and then do the fix at PRE_STREAM_ENDING, and you will have full control over the SOAP Envelope.

Thank you all for your responses. It sucks but it works, and is reasonably easy to disconnect when we have the time to do it properly (!!).

Comment: Also - by the way - subsequently I found that Apache Camel can sit in front of Spring-WS and perform the same, without needing as much work as CXF. So before considering moving to CXF, I'd recommend seeing if Camel will fit your needs first.